# Creating a program that can Ping multiple IP addresses from a dropbox Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, ping

Can any one point me in the right direction, I am looking to create a simple program with Visual Studio C# that can Ping multiple IP address from a combobox and open the ping result within a command prompt.

for example.

Mums PC - (IP Address)

Dads PC - (IP Address)

Brothers PC - (IP Address)

Sisters PC - (IP Address)

When I click the desired PC I can press a button there will be a constant ping displayed within a listview.

I have researched some interesting Ping examples but none seem to include a constant ping in a list view.

So far I can ping an address with a message box displaying true or false.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

This is what I have so far:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
    using System.Threading;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
     class userData
    {
        private int _value;
        private string _name;

        public int Value

        {

            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = value; }
        }

        public string Name

        {

    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; }
    }


        public userData(string name, int value)
        {
            _name = name;
             _value = value;

        }

        public override string ToString()
        {

            return _name;
        }

    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.Items.Add(new userData("172.16.195.54", 1));
        comboBox1.Items.Add(new userData("172.16.195.53", 2));

        comboBox1.Items.Add(new userData("172.16.195.52", 3));


    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool pinging = false;
        Ping isPing = new Ping();

        try
        {
            PingReply reply = isPing.Send(comboBox1.Text);
            pinging = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;

        }
        catch (PingException)
        {

            //return false

        }
        MessageBox.Show("" + pinging, "Result");


    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        userData selectedData = (userData)comboBox1.SelectedItem; label1.Text = selectedData.Name + ":" + selectedData.Value;
    }


}


}
```

I want my combo box to display text instead of an IP address so Mums PC is equal to 172.16.195.52. but I am stuck. also I want it too display a constant ping within a listview currently this is just displaying a message box..

Comment: Well, the command prompt doesn't come with comboboxes, which is a requirement as you stated in your question..

Comment: Hi, I mean a drop down box that uncludes multiple address. you pick an address then press a button. Now the results are displayed in a command prompt is that not possible?

Comment: There are no UI elements to a command prompt (aka a Console application). Only input and output as text

Comment: if not the results can be displayed in a list view the main issue is the drop down.

Comment: This is what I have got, I am stumped pretty new to this. if you can set me right that would be great.

Comment: Just edited my post if you could help

Comment: Could any one help? Or should i delete the post